# Display file from Storage path laravel

Tags: php, laravel-7, file-storage

I have a file stored in storage directory in Laravel 7. The sub directory is storage/app/public/personnel-docs/nameofile.ext.

I have done `php artisan storage:link` and therefore, on my local which is a windows 10 machine I can access it by the following url

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/personnel-docs/nameofthefile.ext

But where it is hosted on a LIVE linux server, when I try the same url as follo

> http://theliveurl/storage/personnel-docs/nameofthefile.ext
> It returns a 404 Not found response.

I have also run `php artisan storage:link` on the server and the problem persists.

I have checked and confirmed that the file is present on the folder but it just does not return/display as expected.

I will appreciate any effort to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: Have you've done this step on the server? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk, and verified that the link is created?

Comment: check permissions of directory. in linux every directory has its permission you should set permission to ```777``` or ```775``` first then  call ```php artisan storage:link```

Comment: I have done all these. Still, same result.